# What in the world does this code do? (C#)

Tags: vb.net, lambda, c#-to-vb.net

I've been reading a book which is in C#. I'm a VB.NET developer (and a very junior one at that) and I'm having a lot of trouble with the following code that contains lots of things I've never seen before. I do have a basic knowledge of Lambda Expressions.

```
public List<T> SortByPropertyName(string propertyName, bool ascending)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "N");

    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
        (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName),
        typeof(object)), param);

    if (ascending)
    {
        return this.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression).ToList<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return this.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpression).ToList<T>
    }
}
```

Could anybody illuminate me as to what this code is doing and what concepts are being used?
I am also trying to convert this code into VB.NET with little luck so any help there would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Is it me, or is the code broken?  Where is T defined?

Comment: @Mike: I'm assuming this is in a generic class, perhaps something that inherits from List<T>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, the code is sorting something (presumably a list?) by the specified property name in either ascending or descending order. There must already be a generic type `T` specified somewhere else in this class.

The code creates a new `ParameterExpression` by calling `Expression.Parameter`, then passes that parameter into the `Expression.Lambda` function, which creates a new lambda expression.

This expression is then used to sort the list by calling the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` function (the choice depending on the `ascending` parameter) and returns the sorted list as a new `List<T>`.

I'm not in front of Visual Studio at the moment, but this should be a sufficiently close translation to VB for you.

```
Public Function SortByPropertyName(ByVal propertyName as String, ByVal ascending as Boolean) as List(Of T)
    Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "N")

    Dim sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), GetType(Object)), param)

    If ascending Then
        return Me.AsQueryable(Of T).OrderBy(Of T, Object)(sortExpression).ToList()
    Else
        return Me.AsQueryable(Of T).OrderByDescending(Of T, Object)(sortExpression).ToList()
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam. The main problem I'm having is with this line: 
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), typeof(object)), param);

What does <Func<T, object>> do? Is it saying that a generic function will be returned by Expression.Lambda()?

Comment: Hmm...VS2008 doesn't seem to like:
"return Me.AsQueryable(Of T).OrderBy(Of T, Object)(sortExpression).ToList()"

I've tried: Return Queryable.AsQueryable(Of T)(Me).OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList()

and it seems to like that, although I'm not sure if it's doing the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Return Me.AsQueryable.OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList
```

See also: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Generic_Sorting.aspx